# Problem spawning robot in STDR Simulator

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of all, I'm running ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

When I run

```
roslaunch stdr_launchers server_with_map_and_gui_plus_robot.launch
```

in the terminal I get the following:

```
started roslaunch server http://192.168.13.28:52368/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.20

NODES
  /
    robot_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    robot_spawn_oskar_HP_29441_9071257298126346751 (stdr_robot/robot_handler)
    stdr_gui_node_oskar_HP_29441_5522075350354395430 (stdr_gui/stdr_gui_node)
    stdr_server (stdr_server/stdr_server_node)
    world2map (tf/static_transform_publisher)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.13.28:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[robot_manager-1]: started with pid [29459]
process[stdr_server-2]: started with pid [29460]
process[world2map-3]: started with pid [29461]
process[stdr_gui_node_oskar_HP_29441_5522075350354395430-4]: started with pid [29467]
[ INFO] [1471878075.227631692]: Loading map from image "/opt/ros/indigo/share/stdr_resources/maps/sparse_obstacles.png"
process[robot_spawn_oskar_HP_29441_9071257298126346751-5]: started with pid [29481]
[ INFO] [1471878075.257817991]: Read a 775 X 746 map @ 0.020 m/cell
**[ERROR] [1471878075.753220639]: Failed to load nodelet [robot0] of type [stdr_robot/Robot] even after refreshing the cache: Failed to load library /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libstdr_robot_nodelet.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = libstdr_omni_motion_controller.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
[ERROR] [1471878075.753305932]: The error before refreshing the cache was: Failed to load library /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libstdr_robot_nodelet.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = libstdr_omni_motion_controller.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)**
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'stdr_robot::DoubleFrameIdException'
  what():  Could not spawn robot. Robot didn't respond within time or registered with incorrect name.
**[robot_spawn_oskar_HP_29441_9071257298126346751-5] process has died [pid 29481, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/stdr_robot/robot_handler add /opt/ros/indigo/share/stdr_resources/resources/robots/pandora_robot.yaml 1 2 0 __name:=robot_spawn_oskar_HP_29441_9071257298126346751 __log:=/home/oskar/.ros/log/8bae2e84-6863-11e6-b00c-3402868ad0cc/robot_spawn_oskar_HP_29441_9071257298126346751-5.log].
log file: /home/oskar/.ros/log/8bae2e84-6863-11e6-b00c-3402868ad0cc/robot_spawn_oskar_HP_29441_9071257298126346751-5*.log**
```

Also, loading or creating a robot using the buttons in the STDR Simulator GUI gives the same error.

Any idea as to what might cause this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242171/problem-spawning-robot-in-stdr-simulator/) by [Oskedosk](https://answers.ros.org/users/27807/oskedosk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-08-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-08-22**:
Is this a duplicate / cross-post of [stdr-simulator-ros-pkg/stdr_simulator#195](https://github.com/stdr-simulator-ros-pkg/stdr_simulator/issues/195)?

**Comment by [Oskedosk](https://answers.ros.org/users/27807/oskedosk/) on 2016-08-23**:
Yes, it is a cross-post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was a bug in the stdr_simulator. The omni_motion_controller library was missing from the install targets.
Further information @ https://github.com/stdr-simulator-ros-pkg/stdr_simulator/issues/195

---

Originally posted by [Oskedosk](https://answers.ros.org/users/27807/oskedosk/) with karma: 16 on 2016-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Oskedosk](https://answers.ros.org/users/27807/oskedosk/) on 2016-09-01**:
Can someone mark this answer as correct? I need more than 10 points to do it myself. Thanks!